# Return rows around row with a certain value with joins

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, row-number

I have fairly complicated join query from which I want to select a few rows around a result with a certain id.

The query currently looks something like this:

```
WITH results AS 
  (
    SELECT t1.id,  t1.position, t1.points, t2.name
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.position ASC, t1.points DESC) AS rn
      FROM Table1 t1
      JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.Table1id
      /* Several more joins here, some of which limit the result set */
  )
SELECT * FROM results
WHERE rn < ( SELECT rn+3 FROM results WHERE  id = @someid ) 
AND rn > ( SELECT rn-3 FROM results WHERE id = @someid )
```

Is there a better way to solve this? Most of all I'm worried about performance with these multiple calls to a possibly huge CTE.

The query is run on a **SQL 2008** server.

Comment: In SQL 2012 you have the `LAG` and `LEAD` functions. But if you're on SQL 2008 or before, that won't help

Comment: That would have done it but I'm on SQL 2008, sadly...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pull the joins out of the CTE.
That way the query optimizer has a chance filter out rows before processing the joins.

```
WITH results AS 
  (
    SELECT t1.id,  t1.position, t1.points
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.position ASC, t1.points DESC) AS rn
      FROM Table1 t1     
  )
SELECT results.id,  results.position, results.points, t2.name
FROM results
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = results.Table1id
      /* Several more joins here */
WHERE rn < ( SELECT rn+3 FROM results WHERE id = @someid ) 
  AND rn > ( SELECT rn-3 FROM results WHERE id = @someid )
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, only that in this case the joins are also used to limit the data shown. I'd still need a (possibly huge) `WHERE id IN(/*joins in here*/)` inside the CTE to get the row numbers right, as well as joins outside the CTE to get to the data in them. Maybe it'd still be better performance-wise, though...

Comment: From you sample I assumed that join did not limit rows.  Until you test on real data just guessing.   It depends on how much rn filters versus joins, indexes, and decisions made by query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another cte to help form the filter:

```
WITH results AS (
    SELECT
        t1.id
      , t1.position
      , t1.points
      , t2.name
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.POSITION ASC, t1.points DESC) AS rn
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.Table1id
    /* Several more joins here, some of which limit the result set */
    ),
filter AS (
    SELECT
        rn
    FROM results
    WHERE id = @someid
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM results
WHERE rn < ( SELECT rn + 3 FROM filter )
AND rn > ( SELECT rn - 3 FROM filter )
```